# wdContextMenu get clicked element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this context menu for a right click on table:tr elements:
http://www.downloadjavascripts.com/list/javasitelll99/Details.aspx

It works fine! and I defined a function for action handling.

```
var option = { width: 150, items: [
    { text: "Edit", icon: "public/images/sample-css/wi0126-16.gif", alias: "1-1", action: menuAction },
    { text: "Activate", icon: "public/images/sample-css/ac0036-16.gif", alias: "1-2", action: menuAction },
    //this is normal menu item, menuAction will be called if this item is clicked on
    { text: "Deactivate", icon: "public/images/sample-css/ei0021-16.gif", alias: "1-3", action: menuAction },
    //this is a split line
    { type: "splitLine" },
    //this is a parent item, which has some sub-menu items
    { text: "Delete", icon: "public/images/sample-css/ei0021-16.gif", alias: "1-3", action: menuAction },
    { type: "splitLine" },
    { text: "Item Four", icon: "public/images/sample-css/wi0124-16.gif", alias: "1-5", action: menuAction },
    { text: "Group Three", icon: "public/images/sample-css/wi0062-16.gif", alias: "1-6", type: "group", width: 180, items: [
        { text: "Item One", icon: "public/images/sample-css/wi0096-16.gif", alias: "4-1", action: menuAction },
        { text: "Item Two", icon: "public/images/sample-css/wi0122-16.gif", alias: "4-2", action: menuAction }
    ]
    }
]
};


function menuAction(){
    alert(this.data.alias);
}
```

But, now I want to get the id of the clicked table:tr element.
How to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that tableId is the id of your table this function should help you:

```
function getIdOfRowByIndex(tableId, rowIndex) {
    return document.getElementById(tableId).rows[rowIndex].id;
}
```

If you have a tr element, then this function should help you:

```
function getIdOfRow(trElement) {
    return trElement.id;
}
```

You can use jQuery to simplify your tasks, but these functions are technology-agnostic to help those who do not want/can use jQuery too.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myElementId;

var option = { ...
    onShow: applyrule,
    onContextMenu: BeforeContextMenu
};

function menuAction() {
    alert(myElementId);
}

function applyrule(menu) {  
    myElementId = this.id
}
```